# SSIS expression for getting last friday and last friday 4 weeks ago

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, expression, etl

I'm looking for the expression for using in SSIS to get the most current Friday and the last Friday from 4 weeks ago.

I was able to get this:

```
DATEPART( "dw", GETDATE() ) == 2 ? GETDATE() : DATEADD( "day", -( DATEPART( "dw", GETDATE() ) +1), GETDATE() )
```

but I'm not sure if it will work for example next week properly, and I don't know how to use it for 4 Fridays ago (I tried adding 28 but that doesn't seem to make the trick)

[image]

Comment: So, try it for some dates?  What were the results? The expected results? Is most current mean last Friday, or this coming Friday?  If run on Friday, do you expect the current date?

Comment: The process will be run on Mondays (or during the weekend, not sure) but for sure not exactly on Friday, so that wouldn't be an issue. I don't know how to try it for different dates, (should I change my server date?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, there are 2 approaches you can take here, the one I think is easiest is to put it in a script task that writes to the variables. The second, is to embed the SQL code in a SQL script, and pull the results out into a result set. If you're using it as input to another data stream, the second might be worth exploring, but I'll concentrate on the first because it's easier (at least for me). So here goes.

Method 1:

Step 1) Start with 2 variables, both of type DateTime. I named mine User::varLastFriday and User::var4FriAgo, but you can name them anything you want. Keep in mind that unlike most of SQL and Visual Studio, *these are case sensitive*!

Step 2) Create a "Script Task". Note that there a many similar sounding tasks, this is the one with the description "Performs functions that are not provided by the standard Integration Services tasks. ..."

Step 3) Edit your script, set the "Language" to Microsoft Visual Basic (to use my sample, you can do the same in C if you're more comfortable) of whatever year your editor is, I'm using 2015 but this should be similar across other versions, 2008 at least was identical.

Step 4) Still in the script properties, drop down the "Read/Write variables" and check both of your variables, you can't update them if they aren't selected here.

Step 5) Still in the script properties, click the button that says "Edit Script", it will open a Visual Studio window with a skeleton project. You'll modify the code in the "Main" procedure. Here is the code. Note that the declaration of Main and the return value should already exist, you're only inserting what I have between my "Start/End of my custom code" comments

```
Public Sub Main()

      'Start of my custom code
      Dim nDayOfWeek As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, Now)
      Dim nOffset As Integer = 0
      If nDayOfWeek >= 6 Then
         nOffset = 6 - nDayOfWeek
      Else
         nOffset = -1 - nDayOfWeek
      End If
      Dts.Variables("User::varLastFriday").Value = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, nOffset, Now)
      Dts.Variables("User::var4FriAgo").Value = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, nOffset - 28, Now)
      'End of my custom code

      Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
```

Step 6) Save the script, save the task, and connect the task to your other steps so it runs first. It's fast, but you don't want a race condition

That's it, when you run it, it updates both variables with the dates of last Friday and the Friday 4 weeks ago, respectively.

Method 2:
The logic can be written in SQL and put in a "Execute SQL Task" where you can get the results back from a result set. I have a hard time getting this method to work, I can usually fiddle around enough to get it to work eventually but you're probably better off getting help from somebody else if you want to go that route. Here's the code that will generate the dates, though, it will at least give you a start.

```
--DECLARE @TestDate DATE = '2019-08-21' 
DECLARE @TestDate DATE = GETDATE() 
--08-23 is Friday, WEEKDAY 6, 25 is Sunday Weekday 1
--use GETDATE for today
DECLARE @LastFri DATE 
-- >=6 means running on Friday returns today, 
--use >6 if you want running on Friday to return last friday
SET @LastFri = DATEADD(day, IIF(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @TestDate) >= 6 
    ,6-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @TestDate)
    ,-1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @TestDate)),@TestDate)
SELECT @TestDate as IfDayIs , @LastFri as ThenLastFriIs, DATEADD(day, -28, @LastFri ) as Fri4Ago

--Fridays in August: 30, 23, 16, 9, 2 July: 26, 19, 12
```

Comment: But this doesn't work for SSIS, right? I'm trying to use it but it doesn't seem to work there, maybe the formatting is wrong? is for a variable expression

Comment: LOL, I misread as SSRS, I'll get back to you with the SSIS version, though maybe tomorrow morning. Sorry for that!

Comment: nothing to apologize for! thank you very much for taking the time to help me, I really appreciate it  :)  good night!

Comment: OK, check out this version, I'm headed home but I'll check back in the morning. Let me know what version of SSIS you're using, I have several installed and that might help if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: I have tried with the visual basic approach and it seems is not putting the values on the variables. I'll keep fiddling with it

Comment: This worked :) I was able to make it work with the SQL task :) thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help, this site has saved me days of work, I'm happy to pay it forward :-) As to not getting the VB to work, it's a powerful tool and worth exploring a bit more when you have time, try setting a breakpoint inside the script and look at the values you are about to assign - usually either the value isn't right, the name of the variable isn't exact, or the variable wasn't marked read/write in the script block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL script to do the same. Add execute SQL Task to your Process. Create an Object type variable as you will need that to store the two dates.

Then if you run the below script, it will give you last friday and friday before 4 weeks. (You can choose the fridays any number of weeks ago by changing the days value)

```
(
  SELECT getdate() DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DateValue - 1
  FROM    mycte   
  WHERE   DateValue - 1 > DATEADD(day,-34, GETDATE())
)                                                                                           
select DateValue from (
SELECT  DateValue,DATEPART(DW, DateValue) as weekday,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by datevalue desc) as Most_Recent_Friday
FROM    mycte
where DATEPART(DW, DateValue) = 6                                                        ) a where Most_Recent_Friday in (1,5)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

The original results would be:

```
DateValue                       |  weekday    |   Most_Recent_Friday
2019-08-16 09:46:25.330         |  6          |   1
2019-08-09 09:46:25.330         |  6          |   2
2019-08-02 09:46:25.330         |  6          |   3
2019-07-26 09:46:25.330         |  6          |   4
2019-07-19 09:46:25.330         |  6          |   5
```

From which I have chosen Friday number 1(last most recent) and Friday number 5 (4 weeks ago), you may chose as your requirement

You will get below output from the given query:

```
2019-08-16 09:46:25.330
2019-07-19 09:46:25.330
```

Last Friday will be `Most_Recent_Friday = 1`, and 4 weeks ago Friday would be `Most_Recent_Friday = 5` or may be 4 whichever you need                                       You can store the results in object variable created and use it in your process

Comment: I'm trying this approach, should I create the Object type variable in the SQL task editor? I have the datetime variables created now for the dataflow task that will use them later
should I do something in the parameter mapping with it?

Comment: You can create Object type variable in your SSIS package. And also one other variable of DateTime type or can use the existing one you already have. Use the Object type variable in Result Set of SQL Execute Task to assign the output of query to Object type variable. Then may be you can use the loop to assign values from object type to DateTime Variable

Comment: Trying to post the screenshot but not able to. Remember to choose Resultset as 'Full Resultset' on General Page in SQL Execute task editor